# Is there a way to deepcopy a list without importing copy.deepcopy?

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
b = x[:]
b[1].append(99)
print(x[1])
```

x[1]=`[1, 2, 3, 99]`

Using the builtin .copy() method `b=x.copy()` is the same, x[1]=`[1, 2, 3, 99]`

and `b = list(x)` is the same too, x[1]=`[1, 2, 3, 99]`

`b=[i for i in x]` is the same too, x[1]=`[1, 2, 3, 99]`

only `import copy` and `b=copy.deepcopy(x)` is
`x[1]=[1, 2, 3]`

is there a way to make x[1]=`[1, 2, 3]` without importing deepcopy() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the lists inside too:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
b = [v.copy() for v in x]
b[1].append(99)
print(x[1])
print(b[1])
```

Comment: what if it's triple or more-dimension list?

Comment: You have to use recursion